# spasttorino/rails-api + activeadmin uninitialized constant Dashboard

Tags: api, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

since I am not able to google somtehing to help me, and believe me I was trying everyhing for few hours now...

here is my situation:
I am running REST API based on ruby 2.0.0 with rails 4.0.0 generated through rails-api gem from santiago pastorino and now I want to have active_admin, to have control over DB tables, just some nice overview of them, like active_admin provides...

and there are few bumps on the road there, first of all, in app_controller a got to include:

```
include ActionController::MimeResponds
include ActionController::ImplicitRender
include ActionController::Cookies

include AbstractController::Translation
include AbstractController::Layouts
```

now I am able to run generate command from readme, but that gives me this at the end:

```
generate  active_admin:assets
/Users/Redrick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- bin/rails (LoadError)
```

but after all this I am able to migrate DB and run server, but when I am trying localhost:3000/admin, I got this error:

[image]

and that is where I am really stuck, please have a look, I am sitting here, so I will provide you additional info needed, thx in advance :)

Comment: Did you make it working?